# count and get top records from multiple tables using code-igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two MySQL tables

```
parent and child
pid pitem
1   a
2   b
3   c

child
cid citem pid
1    aa    1
2    bb    1
3    cc    1
4    dd    2
5    ff    2
6    gg    3
```

I want the following results

```
pid pitem count records of child table
1    a          3
2    b          2
3    c          1
```

How to do it using join or sub query?

Comment: what you have tried so far? show your code, SO is not a platform to write code for you

Comment: Have you tried anything? Just so we dont feel like you are treating us like a free coding resource

Comment: ok , , i have  tried join but nothing, i want only idea not complete code thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join both table and count using group by following this code.

```
<i>SELECT parent.pid, parent.pitem,count(pitem) as totalitem FROM parent  inner join child on parent.pid = child.pid group by parent.pid</i>
```

Comment: thnx dear... very helpful